# Can the Treemap be configured with a different legend location?

Tags: gooddata

I'm using `@gooddata/react-components` version `5.3.0`.  The documentation [here](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/treemap_component.html) suggests that you can supply a [chart config](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/chart_config.html) to the `config` property.  I'm using the same chart config that I'm using for other chart types:

```
{
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    position: 'bottom'
  }
}
```

Unfortunately when I use this config for the Treemap chart type, the legend always renders on the right.  Is this a bug?  Or is it not possible to configure the position of the Treemap's legend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version, 5.3.0 legend position for Treemap can't be configured like for other charts. But in the next version, coming about the end of September, you will be able to configure legend position for all provided charts including Treemap. We will add a note to the doc. Thx for asking!